# Why is my Angular library not included in prod build?

Tags: angular, monorepo

I'm breaking up an Angular project into a monorepo. As a first step I've extracted some of the models in the application so that I have two packages: `models` (a JS library) and `app` (an application). Code in `app` depends on `models` (the next step is to have other packages depend on it):

```
import { LibraryModel } from '@libs/models'
```

My root `tsconfig.json` includes the library path:

```
"paths": {
  "@libs/models": ["projects/models/src/public-api"]
}
```

Running locally with `ng serve` is fine but `ng build app` doesn't  include the `models` library dependency. I've tried building both (`ng build models && ng build app`) and serving out of the `dist` directory but I see issues indicating that the `models` library is not being included at runtime. What am I missing to make sure the library is included in the prod build?

EDIT:

I can get the library to load if I point the `paths` in `tsconfig.json` to the `dist` directory:

```
"paths": {
  "@libs/models": ["dist/models"]
}
```

But by using this developers will need to rebuild `models` on every change . How can I keep the `project/models/src/public-api` path and get this to load in a prod build?

Comment: Did you make some change to angular.json or do you use a webpack external?

Comment: I made changes to angular.json to move the project from single app to multiple projects in a workspace. The original app does use custom webpack config

Comment: Check if you have externals in webpack config. If you have, then you have to provide those libraries externally (in uml format)

Comment: Looks like no externals, just two plugins: `moment-locales-webpack-plugin` and `copy-weback-plugin`

Comment: You shouldn't need them. Try removing webpack extra and use the default provided by angular

Comment: Those are used to keep down the size of `moment` and minify i18n assets, I can't just remove them unfortunately

Comment: you can temporarily to see if it solves your problem and you can isolate the issue.

Comment: I've updated the question with some findings regarding the `dist` directory, please let me know if you guys have any ideas!